# Is a TPM module usable as a physical key between 2 identical computers?

Tags: security, ssd, bios, disk-encryption, tpm

If I have 2 identical machines, can I use the same physical `TPM 2.0 module` in either, if I transfer both the SSD and the TPM module at the same time?

My motherboard (`Asus B150M-A`) has a TPM header, and I'm getting the `TPM 2.0 module` for it. It'd be nice to have Whole Disk Encryption on a drive that I can transfer between a PC at work and a PC at home. Can I transfer both the disk and the TPM module (at the same time) between these 2 machines for a more secure but swappable environment? I do realise the security gaps here, but it beats the alternatives for my budget. Yes, I intend to also use a password in conjunction with the TPM module.

My thinking is that if I use exactly the same model components in each of the computers, it will generate the same signatures and thus the TPM will feel at home in either. I'm not 100% sure about this, so I want to check before buying a whole other machine for this purpose.

Comment: TPM is usually tied to hardware. It might be better to use a pure software solution such as [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) (the successor to TrueCrypt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TPM is usually tied to hardware. It is well-known that a motherboard failure
results in all TPM data lost, as the new motherboard creates a new TPM fingerprint, so a new TPM fingerprint needs to be generated to unlock
by using the recovery key.

One can see by this fact that TPM does not work across hardware components of
the same model, as no two components are absolutely identical,
and that the TPM fingerprint is not transferable between computers.

In addition, not all the metrics used by TPM are known or how exactly they are
used by Windows or the BIOS.
And if that's not enough, TPM implementation varies with different server BIOS
versions, TPM standards, OSes and TPM utility versions.

I suggest using instead of TPM a pure software solution such as [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/),
the successor to TrueCrypt. It will give you the same protection of
Whole Disk Encryption without the hazards, on the virtual disk which is the
VeraCrypt repository file.
The article [VeraCrypt Portable Mode](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Portable%20Mode) would be useful here.

For more information see :

- [Wikipedia : Trusted Platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)
- [How and when to enable hardware-based TPM security on servers](http://searchitoperations.techtarget.com/tip/How-and-when-to-enable-hardware-based-TPM-security-on-servers)

Comment: A TPM is used for more than just full disk encryption - it's also used by things like enterprise VPN clients for securely storing VPN keys and signing client certificates. Parts of Windows depend on a TPM too, such as Measured Boot (rootkit protection), BitLocker, Virtual Smart Cards, and more: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/tpm-recommendations